# Limitar a quantidade de casas decimais de um valores floats que preenchem uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Olá comunidade do Stackoverflow, bom dia.

Estou tentando desenvolver um código que calcule os valores numéricos obtidos a partir de uma equação da física

Eis a forma da equação, [image: t]

onde k , T e pi são valores constantes definidos pelo usuário.
Já lambda é um valor que será percorrido dentro de um intervalo com for e suas respostas armazenadas em uma lista usando o seguinte trecho de código

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


k=2.0
T=25.0+273.0
rhos=[]
for i in range (1,100):

rho = (8*np.pi*k)/i
rhos.append(rho)
print (rhos)
```

os resultados gerados estão saindo nesse formato :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para controlar a quantidade de casas decimais que vão aparecer dentro da lista? Esse controle pode ser feito antes do preenchimento da lista ou apenas depois de preenchida pelo método append?

---

EDIT 1 : Tentei ajustar o código da seguinte forma,

```
 import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


k=2.0
T=25.0+273.0

rhos=[]
for i in range (1,100):

rho = (8*np.pi*k)/i
rhos.append(rho)
print( ".4f" % rho )
```

Porém estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro, aparentemente eu converti as strings para texto na hora de preencher a lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou dar uma estudada sobre o capítulo de formatação com % e tentar ajustar o código,

até lá, obrigado ao Marcelo pela ajuda o/

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro de tudo, os valores salvos na lista rhos serão variáveis do tipo ponto flutuante, não strings(textos), portanto não é necessário limitar a quantidade de virgulas, fazer isso ainda provocaria perda na precisão dos seus cálculos.

No momento de apresentar esses dados ao usuário é que devemos limitar as virgulas, para tal, deve-se usar a formatação de strings em python. Veja mais em [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

A utilização padrão é:

```
variavel = 3.141516
print( "%.2f" %variavel)
# 3.14
```

Onde dentro do seu print, voce coloca entre aspas %.[casas decimais][tipo]. Acima eu coloquei .2 para indicar duas casas decimais, f para indicar que é um numero do tipo ponto flutuante (numero racional).

No seu caso, voce tem uma lista de valores. Voce está imprimindo toda a lista diversas vezes dentro do seu FOR. Não sei se é essa sua intenção. Para imprimir a lista uma única vez remova o print atual e insira depois de rhos.append(rho) o seguinte código:

```
    print( "%.4f" % rho )
```

Isto irá imprimir sua lista, linha por linha, com 4 casas decimais,

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui :/ 

A ideia era exibir a lista de valores apenas uma vez depois que o for tivesse preenchido a lista com os valores da equação. 

Tentei fazer como sugeriu mas acho que fiz algo errado, segue uma print do resultado e do código

Comment: Perdão, esqueci de colocar o % no exemplo, o correto do print seria print( "%.4f" % rho ). No resto seu código vai funcionar

Comment: Opa, acabei de ver sua resposta. Mais tarde edito com o resultado. :)

Comment: Amigo, não funcionou. Não entendi o pq :(

Answer (score 1):

Para você exibir os valores da lista com uma quantidade de casas decimais específicas você pode utilizar a função **[round()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#round)**, especificando o número de casas decimais. Neste caso, o código ficaria desta forma:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


k = 2.0
T = 25.0 + 273.0
rhos = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    rho = round((8 * np.pi * k) / i, 4)
    rhos.append(rho)
print(rhos)
```

Ou desta forma:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


k = 2.0
T = 25.0 + 273.0
rhos = []
for i in range(1, 100): 
    rhos.append(round((8 * np.pi * k) / i, 4))
print(rhos)
```

Ou, utilizando **[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


k = 2.0
T = 25.0 + 273.0
rhos = [round((8 * np.pi * k) / i, 4) for i in range(1, 100)]

print(rhos)
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO 1:** No código que você nos passou, foi importada a biblioteca pandas porém, não utilizada. Isto, poderá gerar algum tipo de erro em algumas IDE's. O correto é só importar uma biblioteca se, de fato, for utiliza-la.

**OBSERVAÇÃO 2:** Percebi que você definiu a variável **T** porém, também não a utilizou. Só defina uma variável se for utiliza-la.